# Is A independent of B conditioned on B?

Tags: causality, independence, conditional-independence, causal-diagram

Does $A \perp\!\!\!\!\!\!\perp B | B$ always hold?

Part of me is like yes: if we know the value of $B$, then more information about $B$ can't tell us anything about $A$, and vice versa.

Consider this causal diagram. Suppose we have conditioned on $B$. Then $A$ and $C$ are independent. So, intuitively I'm like of course $A$ and $C$ must both be independent of $B$, because otherwise association would not be transitive, which doesn't make sense.

```
     B
    / \  
   |   |
   v   v 
   A   C
```

On the other hand,

$$
A \perp\!\!\!\!\!\!\perp B | B\\
P(A, B | B) = P(A | B)P(B | B)\\
P(A, B)/P(B) = P(A)/P(B)\\
P(A, B) = P(A)
$$

...which doesn't make sense.

Maybe I'm somehow confusing the way conditioning is used in causal inference vs how it's used in statistics more broadly?

Some context: I'm working on a piece of causal inference software, and I need to determine whether two sets of random variables ${\bf A}$ and ${\bf B}$ are independent conditioned on some third set of random variables ${\bf C}$. I'm lost on the edge case where ${\bf C} \subset {\bf B}$. I'm hoping for an answer that will help me resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $A$ and $B$ are independent conditional on $B$: this comes down to the question of whether a constant is independent of a random variable (which is covered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585379/independence-between-a-constant-random-variable-and-another-random-variable))

However, independence and association are *not* transitive: $P\perp Q$ and $Q\perp R$ (or the opposite) do not imply anything about $P\perp R$.